# Bug in masonry layout I built using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, layout, resize, masonry

I am trying to build a website using as little code from other people as possible. I built a masonry style layout using JavaScript and it works fine for the most part, except for one bug I found while switching screen sizes in chrome's developer tools function "toggle device toolbar". If I manually resize the window, my layout works as expected. It is only when I switch using the different sizes at the top with given names (such as "mobile s - 320px") that triggers this bug.

The masonry function is a little long but I will do my best to explain it properly. I added inline comments in my function to be as thorough as possible in explaining things.

I first calculate how many cards will fit in the viewport using their width, width of the viewport, and the margin I want between my cards as well as the margin between the cards and the leftmost and rightmost side of the viewport. I want a margin of 1em between my cards and a margin of at least 0.5 rem between my cards and the left and right side of the view port. I calculate that to be "cardsSpace". I then subtract this from the viewport to calculate what the remaining "whiteSpace" will be. I then evenly split this between the left and right side of the page so that my cards will always be centered. After placing the cards in the first "row" of the page, I then figure out in which "column" of the page I should place my next card by calculating which "column" is the shortest one. I then place my card in its respective place, then I update the array that stores the heights of the page "columns" to reflect its new value. I then repeat this process for the remaining cards until there are none left.

Finally I add an event listener to the window for when it resizes, running my masonry layout function whenever the window resizes.

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
const heights = [];
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.card'); //getting all of the cards from the page
let margin = 0;
let windowWidth = 0;
let colWidth = 0;
let cardsSpace = 0;
let colCount = 0;
let whiteSpace = 0;
let min = 0;
let index = 0;

// function that places cards where they should be to get a pinterest like layout
function setupBlocks() {
  // getting window width, width of a card, and setting the margin to be equal to one rem
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  colWidth = blocks[0].clientWidth;
  margin = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
  // calculating how many cards fit in a "row" of the viewport
  colCount = Math.floor(windowWidth / (colWidth + margin));
  // calculating the space the cards will take (including the margin I want between them as well as the 
  // minimum margin between the cards and the left and right side of the page)
  cardsSpace = colCount * (colWidth + margin);
  // calculating the whitespace that will remain
  whiteSpace = windowWidth - cardsSpace;
  // only placing the cards that fit in the first row in their appropriate places
  for (let i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    // I want the white space to be divided evenly on the left and right side of the page
    blocks[i].style.left = `${(whiteSpace + margin)/ 2 + (colWidth + margin) * i}px`;
    // placing the cards at the top of their container and letting top margin take care of the rest 
    blocks[i].style.top = '0px';
    // storing height of each of these cards in an array called "heights" 
    heights.push(blocks[i].offsetHeight + margin);
  }
  // placing the remainder of the cards
  for (let i = colCount; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    // calculating the smallest value in the array of heights
    min = Math.min(...heights);
    // calculating the index of this of this smallest value
    index = heights.findIndex(n => n === min);
    // placing a card below the shortest card column
    blocks[i].style.left = `${blocks[index].offsetLeft}px`;
    blocks[i].style.top = `${heights[index]}px`;
    // updating the heights array to reflect the new height of the column
    heights[index] += (blocks[i].offsetHeight + margin);
  }
  // resetting the heights array to reuse this function if needed
  heights.length = [];
};

// waiting until everything has loaded to run the function that places cards where they 
// should be 
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        setupBlocks();
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', setupBlocks, {signal: controller.signal});
```

```css
/* GENERAL STYLES */

:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: calc(1vw + 0.6em);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  --main-color: #557d79ff;
  --secondary-color: #dae0e6;
  --light-gray: #999;
  --accent: #2d2e2f;
  --dark-text: black;
  font-weight: 300;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Container module */

.container {
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: min(90%, 60em);
}

.container--shops {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Default card used for masonry layout */

.card {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4em 4em 4em 4em;
  max-width: 16em;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  margin-top: 1em;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card__body>*+* {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
}

.card__body {
  padding: .5em 0 2em 1.5em;
}


/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

.card__image>a>img {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  border-radius: 4em 4em 0em 0em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Google Fonts! -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome! -->
  <script defer src="all.js"></script>
  <title>Cards & Navbar</title>
  <!-- Custom CSS! -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container container--shops">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ItaV89TNkks" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/d5SZqLkpIrY" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/EipOdzc58Xo" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/MiTpGlCw-o0" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Djtc1T38-GY" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/4YApsoSaNKA" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/2F8LA55VgzE" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ItaV89TNkks" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/d5SZqLkpIrY" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/EipOdzc58Xo" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/MiTpGlCw-o0" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Djtc1T38-GY" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/4YApsoSaNKA" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/2F8LA55VgzE" alt="Avatar">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__body">
        <h3>Best Cafe</h3>
        <h4>Jonathan</h4>
        <p>Cozy cafe with great food and drinks!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it works fine for the most part except for that one edge scenario. Obviously resizing the window using chrome's resizing options is not something that I expect users to do but what worries me is that this behaviour might pop up unexpectedly for people that switch from portrait to landscape, or in a scenario that I haven't unforeseen. The bug can be replicated by opening up chrome's developer tools and toggling the device bar (as I mentioned before), and then switching from a large window such as 1440 or 4k to a small window size such as 320px. Here is an image of what happens when you do this.

[image: Picture of layout bug]

Any ideas why this might be happening? I have gone over my code a bunch of times now and it seems to me that upon changing the resolution, my function should be re-run as I added an event listener for when the window resizes. Thanks in advance for any help or advice, and my apologies for the long post.